# How do I set the eclipse.ini -vm option?

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, maven, eclipse-plugin, m2eclipse

I installed the [Maven](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Maven) plugin for [Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29), and then I got an error like below:

> please make sure the -vm option in eclipse.ini is pointing to a JDK

How do I use the `-vm` option to point to my JDK in eclipse.ini?

Comment: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini

Comment: Make sure that `-vm` comes **before** `-vmargs` in the `eclipse.ini` file.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

My solution is:

```
-vm
D:/work/Java/jdk1.6.0_13/bin/javaw.exe
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-framework
plugins\org.eclipse.osgi_3.4.3.R34x_v20081215-1030.jar
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-eclipse-34-jvm-settings#144349

Comment: On Unix systems use java instead of javaw.exe

Comment: Note that recent versions (2022 or so) of Eclipse already have a -vm option in the eclipse.ini file, just before -vmargs and that -vm overrides a previous -vm option at the begin of file.

Answer (score 68):

eclipse.ini file must have `-vm` on the first line and a path on the second line. Don't try to put everything into one line!

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_07\bin\javaw.exe
```

Comment: Thanks for the "onel line" trick. `-vm "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_07\bin\javaw.exe"` on one line does not work.

Answer (score 48):

Anything after the "vmargs" is taken to be vm arguments. Just make sure it's before that, which is the last piece in eclipse.ini.

Comment: This is the missing bit of information as well as not putting -vm and the path on the same line

Comment: Also one other thing to note, do not open the ini file in notepad as it will display incorrectly. Open it in another editor, e.g. notepad++

Answer (score 25):

There is a wiki page [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Equinox_Launcher#Finding_a_VM.2C_Using_JNI_Invocation_or_Executing_Java).

There are two ways the [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_virtual_machine) can be started: by forking it in a separate process from the Eclipse launcher, or by loading it in-process using the [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) invocation API.

If you specify `-vm` with a path to the actual java(w).exe, then the JVM will be forked in a separate process. You can also specify `-vm` with a path to the jvm.dll so that the JVM is loaded in the same process:

```
-vm
D:/work/Java/jdk1.6.0_13/jre/bin/client/jvm.dll
```

You can also specify the path to the jre/bin folder itself.

Note also, the general format of the eclipse.ini is each argument on a separate line. It won't work if you put the "-vm" and the path on the same line.

Answer (score 13):

> -vm
>
> C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_06\bin\javaw.exe

Remember, no quotes, no matter if your path has spaces (as opposed to command line execution).

See here: [Find the JRE for Eclipse](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F#Find_the_JRE)

Answer (score 12):

My solution for [Ubuntu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29) Linux:

```
-vm
/home/daniel/Downloads/jdk1.6.0_17/bin
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.1.R36x_v20101122_1400.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.2.R36x_v20101019_1345
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
```

Comment: It is important to add this new lines before -vmargs declaration. Like one the top of file.

Answer (score 10):

I am not sure if something has changed, but I just tried the other answers regarding entries in "eclipse.ini" for Eclipse Galileo SR2 (Windows XP SR3) and none worked. Java is jdk1.6.0_18 and is the default Windows install. Things improved when I dropped "\javaw.exe" from the path.

Also, I can't thank enough the mention that `-vm` needs to be first line in the ini file. I believe that really helped me out.

Thus my eclipse.ini file starts with:

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin
```

FYI, my particular need to specify launching Eclipse with a JDK arose from my wanting to work with the m2eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 5):

You have to edit the eclipse.ini file to have an entry similar to this:

```
C:\Java\JDK\1.5\bin\javaw.exe (your location of java executable)
-vmargs
-Xms64m   (based on you memory requirements)
-Xmx1028m
```

Also remember that in eclipse.ini, anything meant for Eclipse should be before the `-vmargs` line and anything for JVM should be after the `-vmargs` line.

Answer (score 4):

The JDK you're pointing to in your eclipse.ini has to match the Eclipse installation.

If you are running a 32- or 64-bit Eclipse, use a 32 or 64-bit Java JDK, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to share this little hack:

A click on the Eclipse's icon indicated a problem with the JRE.
So, I put this command in the destination field of the icon's properties:

```
C:\...\eclipse.exe -vm c:\'Program Files'\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\bin\javaw
```

Thinking that the "'" would solve the problem with the space in the path.
That did not function. Then, I tried this command:

```
C:\...\eclipse.exe -vm c:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.7.0_51\jre\bin\javaw
```

with success

Answer (score 2):

I know that there exists a command line option, `-vm`, to specify the path to the executable of the Java runtime. This may be the same as in eclipse.ini.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a jre folder, which contains bin, lib, etc files copied from a Java Runtime distribution, in the same folder as eclipse.ini, you can set in your eclilpse.ini

```
-vm
jre\bin\javaw.exe
```

Answer (score -2):

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
512m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Xms2000m
-Xmx3512m
```

Comment: This does not set the JVM and is needlessly requesting huge amounts of memory.