# Having problems pinning Eclipse Juno/Luna/Mars shortcut to windows 7 taskbar

Tags: windows-7, eclipse-juno, eclipse-luna, eclipse-mars, eclipse-neon

I can't seem to properly pin a shortcut to Juno. I've never had this problem with earlier versions of Eclipse.

I've already tried this approach [How to make Eclipse behave well in the Windows 7 taskbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234626/how-to-make-eclipse-behave-well-in-the-windows-7-taskbar)
But that didn't do it for me.

What happen is that when I run eclipse.exe the new shiny Juno icon is shown in the taskbar, but when it's done loading and I get to choose workspace the icon switches to a "Java EE IDE"-icon and pinning that icon doesn't work.

Anyone experience the same problem?

Comment: This does the trick in `Eclipse Luna`. First unpin the eclipse icon from the taskbar. Open the eclipse.ini file (`C:\Program Files\eclipse\eclipse.ini`) and at the beginning of the file write -vm  and in the next line the path to your jre ( `C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin`). Now start eclipse and wait till it opens the main screen, now pin the icon in the taskbar. Now it won't show anymore two icons when you start eclipse.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I was having the same problem, the new eclipse juno icon at first and then the old eclipse ide ee icon in windows taskbar. what I did was to search for png files in the eclipse plugin folder and there try to identify the new icons and the old ones.

I found that the old ones were coming from eclipse-juno\plugins\org.eclipse.epp.package.jee_1.5.0.20120131-1544 on my computer and the new ones were located in eclipse-juno\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.2.0.v201206081400.

In the epp jee folder I created a backup for javaee-ide_x16, _x32 and _48 png files and then copied from the org.eclipse.platform folder the icons eclipse_16, _32 and _48 png files to the epp jee folder and renamed them to javaee-ide_x16, _x32 and _48.

After that I restarted eclipse juno and the taskbar icon was the new shiny one.

Hope this helps,
Cheers

Comment: This solution doesn't answer the stated problem: OP cannot pin the icon to the taskbar. It just talks about changing the icon.

Comment: I've been doing the "easier solutions" proposed in other comments for a single Eclipse instance for years.  This solution is much better for me when I have to keep two versions of Eclipse around (currently Juno and Luna). Thank you!

Answer (score 46):

I was facing the same issue. I did a couple of things:

1.Added this to the **beginning** of eclipse.ini

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jre6/bin/server
```

2.Updated the eclipse definitions - using check for updates from within eclipse. I still didn't get the pin option (icon showed Java EE)

3.Updated Windows and restarted my system.

And voila! It worked! Hope it does for you too!

Comment: For me just point 1 did the trick, thanks! (Eclipse Juno, Java 7 64-bit)

Comment: After step 1, pin the taskbar icon to get the new icon.

Comment: Step one was all I needed to do.  The only difference was I used jre7 instead of jre6.  Thanks!

Comment: Since I added this line, My eclipse takes too much time at start up. After pinning it to taskbar, I just removed it and eclipse's performance is back!!

Comment: You don't have to point Eclipse to the server version (which, I think, is only present in JDK installs). For me, `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin` works well. I also need only step 1.

Comment: Thnx man (Step 1 worked for me ) Windows 7 64bit , jre7 , jdk 1.7 , eclipse juno 32bit

Answer (score 6):

If you create a shortcut pointing to the executable, you can pin the shortcut to the taskbar.

Answer (score 3):

The solution by *ganeshk* did not work for me. Then I found easy solution on the [Eclipse Bugzilla](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=314805).

You need to  **pin a running instance of Eclipse**, then it behaves as expected.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer works. However it changes the feature icon that appears on the **About Eclipse** panel too, which then clashes with the one for the **Eclipse.org** feature.

In order to get the proper **Java EE IDE** icon on the About panel for the **Eclipse Packaging Project** edit the **about.ini** file that resides in the same folder where the icons are and update "**featureImage=**" to point to the old _x32 icon.

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Doing a little experimentation, it appears that the shiny Juno icon will appear if you do a bare-bones Eclipse installation, but if you install the Java or Java EE edition (which is the one you appear to have, Olle) then that icon gets overwritten on the taskbar as soon as the software loads. I, too, am disappointed that I can't have the shiny new icon on my taskbar, but I need the Java plugins and I'm not willing to install them all manually in order to get a nice icon.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, have you *verified* that your installation really uses the VM pointed at in the eclipse.ini (by checking it in the about dialog -> Installation details -> Configuration) and that it is indeed the DLL version of the JVM, not the executable?

And can you verify whether or not it works for you with the Classic (or even platform binary only) download of Juno? That may sound silly, but your note about it using another icon after launching (because of your selected Juno package) made me think that Windows might somehow be confused by those different icons.

Comment: Thanks for answering!  I checked my VM-configuration in Eclipse and it pointed to jvm.dll. I also made sure that my eclipse.ini used the exact same path.  I'm not sure what you mean by Classic download/installation. I got my 64-bit download from: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/junor

Answer (score 1):

http://rianjs.net/2010/11/how-to-pin-eclipse-to-the-windows-7-taskbar

This worked for me. (Windows 7 with Eclipse Juno 4.2 and jre7)

Answer (score 1):

this worked great for me... but not at first... because I added the lines to the end of eclipse.ini ... you must add it as the first lines

http://androblip.huiges.nl/2011/10/11/how-to-get-eclipse-to-pin-to-taskbar-in-windows-7/

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

1 - Copy / paste the executable "eclipse.exe" on the desktop

2 - Pinning  to Taskbar

3 - Delete the desktop executable

4 - Right-click on the eclipse icon in the taskbar > right click on the eclipse icon in the list > Properties

5 - Change the path to the executable (target : ..../eclipse.exe) and change the directory  (Start in:)

Strange but it works for me !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can pin it by right-clicking on the executable file shown in an Explorer window.

Comment: Because for people having the described problem, you then have two Eclipse icons (one pinned, and the other one for the running instance)

Comment: @peci1 This is what does Win to me for many programs, and it did it even before I ran into the problem this Question is about.

Answer (score 0):

I had another Eclipse (3.7.2) already pinned in the task bar. That shortcut was pointing to the **same VM** as the new Eclipse (4.2.0). I had to unpin the 3.7.2 and then REBOOT the operational system. Otherwise Windows would not allow me to pin the new Eclipse. The right click even started, so no options to pin was displayed!

If I let the old pin to the 3.7.2 in the task bar and then started the 4.2.0, after loading my workspace the active icon in the task bar always changed to the 3.7.2 pin. So.. well, I think you need to unpin your old Eclipse (if the case), reboot your OS and then you open and pin your new Eclipse. Perhaps restart the explorer.exe would do the trick?

Just one note, I removed the pin to the 3.7.2. Don't know if you can have multiples pins to multiples Eclipses with the same -vm argument.

--- Edit ---
Nope, restarting the "explorer.exe" doesn't work. =)

Answer (score -1):

If you have already installed eclipse
Search for eclipse.exe file in your computer and then create a shortcurt or Pin it on Taskbar.

If you have not installed eclispse. downlaod the right version from (http://eclipse.org/) and install.