# How to make Eclipse behave well in the Windows 10 taskbar and program search?

Tags: eclipse, windows-10

This question is very similar to its famed windows 7 [counterpart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234626/how-to-make-eclipse-behave-well-in-the-windows-7-taskbar), but the same solution no longer works on windows 10 so it seems like the new platform is worthy of its own question.

Of course, everybody who uses eclipse on windows has hit this age old bug at one point of another - documented [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=314805) - but for those who aren't familiar, the TL;DR is that you get two taskbar icons for eclipse because the eclipse launcher (eclipse.exe) and the eclipse workspace (JVM) are two separate processes and you can't pin the workspace process. It looks like they wont fix this in the near term so we're reliant on workarounds for now.

Has anybody gotten eclipse to work with Windows 10 taskbar? What about start menu search (a.k.a. cortana). The post [here](http://pranavraulkar.blogspot.com/2013/03/creating-custom-tiles-for-eclipse.html) walks through start menu pinning but windows search doesn't pick up the shortcut, unfortunately

Comment: The fix here is really something the eclipse team should be handling: Both parts of eclipse should be [using the same AppUserModelId](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2015/08/10/10634022.aspx) and that way, windows will treat them as logically the same object. That said, it does seem like some workarounds for apps got dropped in the move to win10, because I noticed that this started happening for things like iTunes (and iTunes released an update to fix it on their end, iirc)

Comment: Thanks for the info - I'll relay it to the eclipse community in bugzilla

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer was staring me in the face all along - at least for the taskbar. Full credit to Timo Kinnunen who had already posted this workaround in the in the [bugzilla report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=314805)

1. Edit the plugin.xml file of your selected Eclipse version ("product") and erase the following line:

This should be done before starting the installation for the first time,
because the property value gets cached and the change won't have effect
before the cache is cleared. The correct file to edit varies:

- \plugins\org.eclipse.sdk_4.4.0.v20140123-1600
- \plugins\org.eclipse.epp.package.standard_2.1.0.20131103-0830
- \plugins\org.eclipse.epp.package.jee_4.5.0.20150621-1200

2. Edit eclipse.ini to add these lines at the end before the line `--launcher.appendVmargs`, add this:

   -vm
   "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll"

This causes the JVM to be launched in the same process as eclipse.exe rather
than as a child process and avoids the intricacies of Host Processes with
AppUserModelIDs.

3. Launch Eclipse by double-clicking eclipse.exe. Only once the workspace is open select "Pin this program to taskbar" from the taskbar icon.

Comment: `This should be done before starting the installation for the first time` What do those of us who have already run Mars do, other than uninstall and reinstall from scratch?

Comment: To clarify terms used in the answer and above comment, "install" means extracting the zip contents to the directory you want and "uninstall" means to delete the directory from your hard drive completely. I could not get the instructions to work until I deleted the eclipse directory, started fresh by unzipping to the same location, then followed the directions.

Comment: Simply closing Eclipse and unpinning the taskbar shortcut(s), followed by your step 3 worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Simply removing the property from `plugin.xml` and re-adding the shortcut worked for me on Windows 10 - I didn't have to reinstall Eclipse or edit `eclipse.ini`

Comment: Simply added the -vm option (with the path for the jvm) and unpinning/starting/pinning worked (had to do it twice I guess though).

Comment: I also was able to get it to work with just the `-vm` argument in `eclipse.ini` - crucial point is the `jvm.dll` path must be on a separate line!

Comment: I couldn't find the plugin.xml file.  But adding the vm arg worked for me.

Comment: If the `-vm` argument is not on a separate line, it needs to be in double quotes for it to work

Comment: The line to remove is:
`<property name="appName" value="Eclipse"/>`
For Eclipse 2021-12 that line is in:
`org.eclipse.platform_4.22.0.v20211124-1800\plugin.xml`

Answer (score 51):

This is an updated version of icyitscold's answer that doesn't require uninstalling/reinstalling eclipse.

1) Unpin any eclipse icons
 2) Run "eclipse.exe -clean" to clear the cache and then close eclipse
 3) Modify 
 `./plugins/org.eclipse.epp.package.xxxxx/plugin.xml`
The folder varies based on which version of eclipse you are using: j2ee, java, c++ etc.
Change the appName property - call it "MyEclipse" or something.
 4) Edit the eclipse.ini to add:

```
-vm
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll
```

Or wherever your JDK is before the line:

```
--launcher.appendVmargs
```

5) Run eclipse and open a workspace, pin the eclipse icon after it's loaded.

Credit to icyitscold, Ruslan Gainutdinov, Timo Kinnunen

Comment: This worked perfectly. Actually for me step 2 and 4 wasn't necessary.

Comment: @Shannon-Smith Sadly this didn't work for me. I do "MyEclipse" in my title now, which I find oddly amusing, but when eclipse is fully up and running, (with no pinned) and I pin to Taskbar, a second icon is created. If I start a second instance, that icon is only active while splash screen is open. Once spash has finished and a new eclipse window opens, it stacks with the other eclipse window. The ide window icon has an "unpin" option, it unpins the splash icon.

Comment: Steps 1 and 2 were enough for me on Windows 8.1. After I started Eclipse with -clean option I got the "Pin to taskbar" option on running eclipse window.

Comment: Thanks, Cakan. Your solution (using only steps 1 and 2) also works on Windows 10.

Comment: For me, just positions 1 and 5 were sufficient on a windows 2016 machine

Comment: And for me, only Step 4 was required. I like this one as I often tweak `eclipse.ini` anyway to set JVM memory & GC options. Worked on Win 7 & 10, Java 7 through 9. (Tested with the "Eclipse SDK" product, if that matters.)

Comment: For me, I had to replace the default `-vm .../bin/javaw.exe` with `-vm .../bin/server/jvm.dll` and I could pin Eclipse onto the taskbar. Thanks!

Comment: Step 3 wasn't possible; there's no such file. But for the rest, it seems to work on Win11.

Comment: This didn't work for me with Windows 10 and Eclipse 2021-12. I had to use the answer from icyitscold. And the file to edit was `plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.22.0.v20211124-1800\plugin.xml`.

Comment: I'm running Windows 11 and using Eclipse 2023-03, none of the solutions here work because my plugins folder only contains a single jar file, no `plugin.xml` anywhere.

Answer (score 28):

## Fix for Eclipse Neon + Oxygen + Photon + 2019‑06

This was pretty simple 2 step process, no editing required.

1. Close all Eclipse instances and unpin the non-working icon
2. Open up Eclipse. DO NOT PIN yet. Select a workspace, let the main Eclipse window load. Pin that (right click on the icon -> Pin to taskbar).

That worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Great, easy and simple fix. Thanks.

Comment: So glad to see that they decided to fix the weird behavior :D Thanks for sharing!

Comment: Works on 2019-06 version

Comment: Works perfectly on 2021-12 version. Thank you for that simple fix without the need to install/uninstall or alter anything.

Answer (score 2):

For windows 10, go to extracted eclipse folder, right click on `eclipse.exe` and

- To pin to taskbar, select `Pin to taskbar`
- To pin to Start menu, select `Pin to Start`

Comment: This works, but it'll still launch the IDE as separate taskbar icon.

Answer (score 0):

This was way easier than I expected..here's what I did in Win 10.

1. Went to unzipped Eclipse folder and right clicked on the Eclipse Icon and 'created shortcut by using Send to Desktop.
2. Once the shortcut appeared on my Desktop,,right clicked the icon and chose 'Pin to Taskbar'

Done!....simple..no?

Comment: This does not work unless you have the -vm specified in the eclipse.ini file, tested on fresh install of Eclipse Neon.1

Answer (score 0):

The steps described in this post worked for me, to get rid of the duplicated item in the taskbar (Windows 10 + eclipse Oxygen):

https://superuser.com/a/932807