# Eclipse 3.6.X setup for m2eclipse

Tags: m2eclipse, ini, eclipse-3.6

I've tried many configurations, but I keep getting the following error upon opening eclipse:

```
Eclipse is running in a JRE, but a JDK is required
```

I've tried following the instructions in the following SA questions: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905611/how-do-i-set-eclipse-ini-vm-option), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142357/what-are-the-best-jvm-settings-for-eclipse)

The things I tried in the `eclise.ini` file:

- Various -vm configurations:

  - -vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
  - -vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\java.exe
  - -vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\bin
  - -vm C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre\bin\java.exe
- Various -vm location :

  - as first line
  - as last line
  - just before -vmargs
  - just before showsplash
- With and without -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion = 1.6

Also, in `eclipse\Window\Preferences\Java\Installed JREs` I added `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\jre` and marked it (and unmarked the default jre6)

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174741/run-eclipse-in-jdk) regarding running eclipse in JDK