# Unable to install m2e lifecycle mappings

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

After updating my Eclipse Kepler version to 20130919-0819 I need to reinstall the m2e lifecycle mappings. But when I try to open the dialog for installing lifecycle mappings (via Preferences or link in POM viewer message) the following error message is shown:

```
"Discovery completed without finding any extensions. Please check your network connection and try again."
```

The Eclipse error log shows the following exception:

```
java.io.IOException: Unable to create temporary file
at java.io.File$TempDirectory.generateFile(Unknown Source)
at java.io.File.createTempFile(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.discovery.compatibility.RemoteBundleDiscoveryStrategy$DownloadBundleJob.call(RemoteBundleDiscoveryStrategy.java:197)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.discovery.compatibility.RemoteBundleDiscoveryStrategy$DownloadBundleJob.call(RemoteBundleDiscoveryStrategy.java:1)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I already tried to use a fresh Eclipse installation as well as a new workspace but the error still remains the same. My network connection is working and I can open the link to the JAR file in a web browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by an incompatibility between p2 and jdk 1.7.0_40 ( see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=417458).

You can try starting eclipse with an older version of the jdk, using the vm argument. See related links :

- http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F#eclipse.ini
- [How do I set the eclipse.ini -vm option?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905611/how-do-i-set-eclipse-ini-vm-option)

Answer (score 0):

Try updating your jdk to a newer version above jdk 1.7.0_40