# Run Eclipse 64Bit and 32Bit version with one setting

Tags: java, eclipse

I have to set the JAVA_HOME to 64bit version JDK to properly run eclipse64 bit. Similar setting has to be done for 32Bit Eclipse version so JAVA_HOME needs to be set 32 bit JDK version. Otherwise I am having "Failed to load the JNI shared library" error.

I have two eclipse versions installed in my windows machine, and I do not want to set corresponding JAVA_HOME before running each eclipse version.

Is there are way of unique setting for both eclipse running?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [specify the VM in `eclipse.ini`](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM).

For Windows this would look something like this:

```
-vm
C:\Java\JDK\1.6\bin\javaw.exe
```

Yes, they should be on two separate lines.

Be sure to specify that *before* any `-vmargs` parameter, as everything after that is interpreted as arguments to the VM (see [this question for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905611/how-do-i-set-eclipse-ini-vm-option)).

Answer (score 1):

You can specify desired JAVA_HOME in eclipse.ini  file. Refer [documentation](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) for details.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to explicitly set the VM argument in each eclipse.ini (32bit and 64bit):
" -vm
/path/to/javaw.exe" (http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini)

where the path correspond to the location of  the appropriate JDK (32bit/64bit)