# how to configure JDK as the default JVM in my workspace

Tags: java, grails, spring-tool-suite

Im trying to create a new grails project using the IDE GGTS (groovy and grails tool suite )
 but it says that grails needs a JDK and  JRE is not enough , I already installed JDK 1.7 and added the JAVA_HOME to the path 
i also copied the grails folder and added a GRAILS_HOME to the path 
in GGTS :

i tried In Window>Preferences>Java>Installed JREs to check JDK1.7.0_51

and

In Window>Preferences>Java>Installed JREs>Execution Environments I choosed JavaSE-1.7 and checked JDK1.7.0_51[perfect match]

the JDK installed is 64 bits and My PC is windows 8 64 bits

but the error persists 
[image]

Comment: Just a hunch: try a 32 bits JDK then. It might be that the runtime detection of whatever plugin is throwing up this dialog is limited.

Comment: Follow this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905611/how-do-i-set-eclipse-ini-vm-option.

Answer (score 12):

We have to make sure that the Java run time of our eclipse IDE points to a JDK instead of a JRE. Here are the steps:

Go to Window->Preferences

[image]

Edit Installed JRE if it is pointing to a JRE installation

[image]

Change it to the JDK installation directory. It is better if you also change the name

[image]

[image]