# ERROR trying to generate classes from a WSDL using maven in spring mvc

Tags: spring, web-services, maven, spring-mvc, wsdl

hi i'm trying to follow this example https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/ and i get the following error in my pom.xml file

this is my pom.xml file, the new part that i added is the part after the comment <-- WEB SERVICES -->

this is the part where is the problem :

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>       
                <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <generatePackage>hello.wsdl</generatePackage>
                    <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                    <schemas>
                        <schema>
                            <url>http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?wsdl</url>
                        </schema>
                    </schemas>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

and here is the entire pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.pruebaWsCompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>app</artifactId>
    <name>PruebaWSproy</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <java-version>1.6</java-version>
        <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
        <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
        <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
        </dependency>   

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>




        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>        
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--WEB SERVICES -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>generate</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>       
                <configuration>
                    <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                    <generatePackage>hello.wsdl</generatePackage>
                    <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                    <schemas>
                        <schema>
                            <url>http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?wsdl</url>
                        </schema>
                    </schemas>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and this is the error that i get i try using maven update in my spring-tools suite IDE but still i get the same error

this is the error

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.12.3:generate failed: A required class was missing while executing org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.12.3:generate: com/sun/codemodel/CodeWriter
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.12.3
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/d:/Users/myUser/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin/0.12.3/maven-jaxb2-plugin-0.12.3.jar
urls[1] = file:/d:/Users/myUser/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb2-plugin-core/0.12.3/maven-jaxb2-plugin-core-0.12.3.jar
urls[2] = file:/d:/Users/myUser/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.7/slf4j-api-1.7.7.jar
urls[3] = file:/d:/Users/myUser/.m2/repository/org/apache/commons/commons-lang3/3.2.1/commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar
urls[4] = file:/d:/Users/myUser/.m2/repository/com/sun/org/apache/xml/internal/resolver/20050927/resolver-20050927.jar
urls[5] = file:/d:/Users/myUser/.m2/repository/junit/junit/4.8.1/junit-4.8.1.jar
urls[6] = file:/d:/Users/myUser/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/1.5.15/plexus-utils-1.5.15.jar
urls[7] = file:/d:/Users/myUser/.m2/repository/org/jvnet/jaxb2/maven2/maven-jaxb22-plugin/0.12.3/maven-jaxb22-plugin-0.12.3.jar
urls[8] = file:/d:/Users/myUser/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-runtime/2.2.11/jaxb-runtime-2.2.11.jar
urls[9] = file:/d:/Users/myUser/.m2/repository/org/glassfish/jaxb/jaxb-xjc/2.2.11/jaxb-xjc-2.2.11.jar
urls[10] = file:/d:/Users/myUser/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugin-tools/maven-plugin-annotations/3.2/maven-plugin-annotations-3.2.jar
Number of foreign imports: 5
import: Entry[import org.sonatype.plexus.build.incremental from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.Scanner from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.DirectoryScanner from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import org.codehaus.plexus.util.AbstractScanner from realm ClassRealm[plexus.core, parent: null]]
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------
 (org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.12.3:generate:default:generate-sources)   pom.xml /PruebaWSproy   line 165    Maven Build Problem
```

+++EDIT

i used this tag  at the start of my plugins tag and this tag at the end  and i no longer have this problem `Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.12.3:generate failed:`

here is how i edited it

```
<build>
    <pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                    <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                </additionalProjectnatures>
                <additionalBuildcommands>
                    <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                </additionalBuildcommands>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!--WEB SERVICES -->

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                <generatePackage>hello.wsdl</generatePackage>
                <forceRegenerate>true</forceRegenerate>
                <schemas>
                    <schema>
                        <url>http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?wsdl</url>
                    </schema>
                </schemas>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

but after i update my maven there are no new packages or classes, this should bring me new classess and packages right?

++++EDIT 2

i try putting this tags but stille no class are generated

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.12</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                        <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                        <generateDirectory>D:/Users/myUser/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.0.RELEASE/ProjectTryWSDL/src/gensrc</generateDirectory>
                        <generatePackage>com.wsdl.src</generatePackage>
                        <schemas>
                            <schema>
                                <url>http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?wsdl</url>
                            </schema>
                        </schemas>              
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

i think that my folder have permissions to create folders by external apps, or do i need to create that folder by mysefl?

+++++ EDIT 3

i added this route in the generate tag

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.12</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsimport</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                        <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                        <generateDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/gensrc</generateDirectory>
                        <generatePackage>com.wsdl.src</generatePackage>
                        <schemas>
                            <schema>
                                <url>http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?wsdl</url>
                            </schema>
                        </schemas>              
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

and this is my properties tags

```
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.1.1.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
    <project.version>0.12.3</project.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven trouble when trying to generate from WSDL file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28501463/maven-trouble-when-trying-to-generate-from-wsdl-file)

Comment: @Tunaki that question dont have solution but is marked as it have a solution

Comment: The author of the plugin stated that this might be a bug. Have you tried to reduce your pom to a minimal example ?

Comment: i edited my question.. i put the pluginmanagement tag to wrap my plugin tags and i no longer have the error, but nothing happends after i update my maven there ano new classes in my project or packages

Comment: It is extremely annoying that a so called "beginners getting started guide" from the Spring.io jokers doesn't work properly with arcane farting about with the guts of the pom.xml file!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change your configuration like below to generate sources.

`generateDirectory` is the actual directory where the source files are created.

`generatePackage` is the package name for the source files you generate from WSDL, so you should find these package sub-folders inside `generateDirectory`

```
      <configuration>
               <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
               <generateDirectory>${project.build.sourceDirectory}/gensrc
                      </generateDirectory>
               <generatePackage>com.wsdl.src</generatePackage>
                <schemas>
                    <schema>
                        <url>http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx?wsdl</url>
                    </schema>
                </schemas>
       </configuration>
```

You can use `mvn jaxb2:generate` to generate source files inside your `project/src/gensrc` directory. For more details on possible configurations, have a look at this [cheat sheet](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki/Configuration-Cheat-Sheet) :)

Comment: here is the path of my eclipse project controller home class `D:\Users\myUser\Documents\workspace-sts-3.6.0.RELEASE\ProjetTryWSDL\src\main\java\com\myCompany\app`

I try putting this path in the    <generateDirectory> tag `D:/Users/myUser/Documents/workspace-sts-3.6.0.RELEASE/ProjetTryWSDL/src/main/java/gensrc`  i put that in the tag   but still no class or packages are generated
i Edited my question with my pom XML after your comment @Arkantos 
do i need to create this folder by myself where eclipse save my projects or is suppose to be created by maven after putting the generate tag

Comment: No you don't have to specify the path in `generateDirectory`, use the configuration as is mentioned in my answer as I'm referring to src directory using implicit maven variables. Once changes to pom are done, try `mvn clean install` from the directory containing pom.xml, that should generate the sources :-)

Comment: One more thing is you should be connected to internet as you're the specifying the src of your WSDL as URL. I assume you're already connected :-)

Comment: i put the same generate tag as you told me bu still :( no class are genereted i try using mvn clean install but it failed since i dont have a tools.jar in some folder, but i dont think that is the problem since i can add depencies without having to do a mvn clean install, i just use the maven update function in eclipse, i edited my question again so you can see is my i miss something, i dont know how is it going to work since i dont have  `${project.build.sourceDirectory}` in my properties tag

Comment: i fix my maven problem now i can execute the mvn command with a BUILD  SUCCESS answer but still there are no classes are  generated or packages or anything

Comment: Do you have an actual jdk installed not just the jre on your system ?

Comment: yes i have the jdk installed i believe is the 7, i also have my JAVA_HOME variable pointing to the jdk path

Comment: @stackUser2000 How did u fix it? can you post answer?

Answer (score 6):

Previously I have this issue because of the plugin version (I try to use 0.12.3)

```
Execution default of goal org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.12.3:generate failed: A required class was missing while executing org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.12.3:generate: com/sun/xml/bind/api/ ErrorListener
```

I don't know if the cause is the same or not but I fixed it by changing the version.
Try this one:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.12.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <schemaLanguage>WSDL</schemaLanguage>
                <generatePackage>soap.servicereq1</generatePackage>
                <schemas>
                    <schema>    
                    <url>http://xxx/Services/ProxyService/ServiceRequest?wsdl</url>
                    </schema>
                </schemas>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Hope it works

Comment: Yes - simply by changing 0.12.3 to 0.12.1 the pom.xml became valid and I could generate the sources

Comment: changing to version 0.12.1 generates required classes and to run the client you need to set -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy_host
-Dhttp.proxyPort=proxy_port as spring boot run argument