# WSDL plugins - In Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot

Error :

> Execution default of goal
>   org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.12.3:generate failed: A
>   required class was missing while executing
>   org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2:maven-jaxb2-plugin:0.12.3:generate:
>   com/sun/xml/bind/api/ErrorListener

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQFkW.png
Spring Boot --
Problem

Comment: Have you don't any research into this issue yourself? I just googled the error and got hundreds of results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven trouble when trying to generate from WSDL file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28501463/maven-trouble-when-trying-to-generate-from-wsdl-file)