# Running Eclipse: can't find Java even though both are 64 bit

Tags: java, eclipse

I downloaded 64-bit Java from Oracle and 64-bit Eclipse and when I run eclipse it gives me **error code 13**.  I tried using the solutions from another user who asked this question but it didn't work. Any suggestions?

Comment: There may be a problem with your Java installation that could be fixed by reinstalling it, but you're not giving us any details to work with.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set the eclipse.ini -vm option?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905611/how-do-i-set-the-eclipse-ini-vm-option)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot run Eclipse; JVM terminated. Exit code=13](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4945178/cannot-run-eclipse-jvm-terminated-exit-code-13)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Andreas hit the nail on the head with his suggested duplicate. The problem is that you are trying to run a 64-bit eclipse with a 32-bit java, or vice versa. Yes, I know you downloaded 64-bit eclipse and 64-bit java, but you didn't tell the 64-bit eclipse to use the 64-bit java. The eclipse.ini file is where you do that, and the -vm option is how.

In addition to the linked question, Eclipse provides a forum post on this subject at https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/198527/ and a guide to using the eclipse.ini file at http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini.

The bottom line: you set the -vm option in the eclipse.ini file. The `-vm` must be on its own line, and the following line must only be the path to your javaw.exe. Both of those lines have to come *before* any `-vmargs` entry.

Once you get that done your 64-bit eclipse will run with the 64-bit java that you downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

Add the vm option and the full path to the javaw.exe 
`-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw.exe -startup`

Comment: No no no, not the command-line arguments. Are we guessing, or do we know?