# Can't run Eclipse: exit code=13/exit code=1/no JRE or JVM found

Tags: java, eclipse

I'am using Eclipse 3.7 from 4 years, I have never faced any issue till now.

Suddenly I started facing different errors on launching eclipse.

I have referred most of the similar issue posted on stackoverflow; fixing one issue results in another sort of issue.
Say when I followed instructions to solve error code=13, on launching I got error code=1 problem, on solving that I got JRE or JDK not available issue.

To let you know about what I have done:
- modified eclipse.ini file
- created PATH environment variable

my eclipse.ini looks like below:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xms40m
-Xmx384m
```

**User variable** created as:

Name: PATH

Value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin

**System variable** created as:

Name: JAVA_HOME

Value: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91

Can someone suggest me in fixing this out.

Comment: have you tried downloading latest version?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/905611/how-do-i-set-the-eclipse-ini-vm-option

Comment: try replacing `-vm` with value `C:\Program Files\IBM\Java71\jre\bin\java.exe`

If you encounter Java was started but returned exit code=1 point the `-vm` option to jvm.dll

`-vm`

`C:\Development\Java\64bit\jdk1.7.0_09\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll`

Comment: Is this 64-bit Windows?

Comment: your -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion is 1.5 . JAVA_HOME is 1.8 ?

Comment: @Manoj I tried -vm path to jvm.dll, on launching it throws "Failed to load the JNI shared library in that provided path"

Comment: @nitind Yes my OS is 64 bit

Comment: @Sampada Yes..as it is in the eclipse.ini file

Comment: Why not try making it the same? either set the version in ini to 1.8 or change JAVA_HOME to 1.5

Comment: @SandeshMendon 64-bit Java can only run a 64-bit Eclipse.

Comment: @SandeshMendon In the `-vm` option, try giving path of the java till `bin` directory. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_91\bin`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like 32/64 bit problem. From launcher.library I see you are using 32 bit eclipse. From the Java path it looks like 64-bit. You can confirm Java version by running Java -version.

Try with 32-bit Java or get a 64-bit Eclipse.

My assumption here is your OS is 64-bit.

Comment: Yes my OS is 64 bit and java version is 1.8 64 bit

Comment: 64-bit Java can only run a 64-bit Eclipse. Likewise for 32-bit Java and 32-bit Eclipse.

Comment: @SandeshMendon Your eclipse may be 32 bit. Try downloading 64 bit version.