# Ecilpse Oxygen.3a Java IDE cannot add window GUI via window builder error opening wizard

Tags: java, eclipse, windowbuilder

I try to use the [Eclipse Oxygen v4.7.3a](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29#Releases) (Oxygen) Java IDE.

I try to use window builder to build a GUI application with Java, but when I try to add the window I have an error message.

I tried to google it, but I cannot even know what that message needs from me.

It says:

---

problem opening wizard

```
The selected wizard could not be started.
Plug-in org.eclipse.wb.swing was unable to load class org.eclipse.wb.internal.swing.wizards.application.NewSwingApplicationWizard.
An error occurred while automatically activating bundle org.eclipse.wb.core.java (528).
```

---

My `java -version` output:

```
OpenJDK version "10" 2018-03-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 10+46-Ubuntu-5ubuntu1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 10+46-Ubuntu-5ubuntu1, mixed mode)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error occur in Eclipse Oxygen.3a on my Mac with Java JDK 10 installed.  There is code in WindowBuilder 1.9 that uses a Java feature that was either altered or dropped in Java 10.  I was able to resolve the problem by making two changes (they assume that a Java 9 JDK is available on your system;  if not, you must install it):

- change the Java VM for Eclipse to one in a Java 9 JDK (using the -vm setting in eclipse.ini; see [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/905611/how-do-i-set-the-eclipse-ini-vm-option) for a good post on how to do that)
- change the JRE for the project to a Java 9 JRE

The first change is the more important one since Window Builder is a development aid running as part of Eclipse.

I made the project JRE change for my own sanity so I didn't have a mix of Java versions.  You may be able to skip that change (I didn't try it).

I still have Java 10 as the default for the system, so you don't have to completely fall back to Java 9 if you install both JDKs.  It may take some tweaking to get both Java 9 and 10 installed and have the one you prefer working as the system default.