# Eclipse RCP - Error launching product built with Tycho

Tags: windows, eclipse, maven, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I have an RCP project built with maven - tycho. Recentlty I was building this project with maven and it was launching well on any host with JavaSE runtime environment installed.

Since some updates (I do not know which) this archive is failing to launch on any Windows host with error log:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 4 0 2022-12-03 14:41:27.751
!MESSAGE FrameworkEvent ERROR
!STACK 0
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator [1]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:463)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$2.run(ModuleContainer.java:1852)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$1$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:136)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1845)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1788)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1750)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.startWorker(SystemModule.java:269)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:468)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.start(SystemModule.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:445)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.launch.Equinox.start(Equinox.java:139)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:338)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:251)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2022-12-03 14:41:27.752
!MESSAGE Bundle initial@reference:file:plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.4.100.v20220620-1617.jar was not resolved.

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator 2 0 2022-12-03 14:41:27.756
!MESSAGE Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator [1]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))"


!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2022-12-03 14:41:27.757
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to acquire application service. Ensure that the org.eclipse.core.runtime bundle is resolved and started (see config.ini).
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:255)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:659)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:596)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1467)
```

I have JavaSE 11, 14 and 15 installed on this machine.

The project is successfully launcing form Eclipse.

Any clues?

I've been reinstalling different Java runtimes, now 3 runtimes is installed.

Comment: Well it is complaining that it isn't running on at least Java 11 so it seems to have found an older Java. If you have multiple Java installs you may need to specify the `-vm` in the rcp ini file.

Comment: Logs usually start with a `!SESSION` followed by the Java version being used - what does that say?

Comment: Yes, it seems Java 8 is also installed on my PC, and after I deinstalled it everything is ok!

Comment: @greg-449 what is the format of -vm argument?

Comment: See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2454767/2670892). That is for the eclipse.ini but the ini for an RCP is the same, just has a different name.

Comment: You can also include/embed Java in your RCP application via [Eclipse JustJ](https://www.eclipse.org/justj/).